# Unable to use Varnish director in another director

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm trying to nest Varnish directors but it's not working in 4.1.10 or 6.4, despite being mentioned in multiple places.

I have two random directors, and I want to add them to a fallback director like this:

```
vcl 4.0;

import directors;
backend alpha { .host = "192.168.0.101"; }
backend bravo { .host = "192.168.0.102"; }

sub vcl_init {
    new primary_director = directors.random();
    primary_director.add_backend(alpha, 1.0);

    new secondary_director = directors.random();
    secondary_director.add_backend(bravo, 1.0);

    new fallback_director = directors.fallback();
    fallback_director.add_backend(primary_director);
    fallback_director.add_backend(secondary_director);
}
```

The [official documentation](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.4/reference/vmod_directors.html#description) supports this case:

> Note that directors can use other directors as backends

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

You can test it yourself by saving the snippet above as `/tmp/test.vcl` and running varnish in Docker:

```
$ docker run -v /tmp/test.vcl:/test.vcl --rm varnish:6.4 varnishd -F -f /test.vcl
Error:
Message from VCC-compiler:
Expression has type INSTANCE, expected BACKEND
('/test.vcl' Line 15 Pos 35) -- (Pos 50)
    fallback_director.add_backend(primary_director);
----------------------------------################--

Expected argument: BACKEND (unnamed argument)

While compiling function call:

('/test.vcl' Line 15 Pos 5) -- (Pos 50)
    fallback_director.add_backend(primary_director);
----##############################################--

Running VCC-compiler failed, exited with 2
VCL compilation failed
```

Answer (score 2):

Big thanks to the people in the Varnish IRC board - they got me to the answer quickly!

Here is the corrected version of my example:

```
vcl 4.0;

import directors;
backend alpha { .host = "192.168.0.101"; }
backend bravo { .host = "192.168.0.102"; }

sub vcl_init {
    new primary_director = directors.random();
    primary_director.add_backend(alpha, 1.0);

    new secondary_director = directors.random();
    secondary_director.add_backend(bravo, 1.0);

    new fallback_director = directors.fallback();
    fallback_director.add_backend(primary_director.backend());
    fallback_director.add_backend(secondary_director.backend());
}

sub vcl_recv {
    set req.backend_hint = fallback_director.backend();
}
```

The key points here are:

1. The correct syntax is `fallback_director.add_backend(primary_director.backend());`
2. Without `set req.backend_hint = fallback_director.backend();`, Varnish will use the first backend that is defined.